# Vite appending assets path to image URLs

Tags: tailwind-css, vite

Using Vite/React/Tailwind, I am trying to set dev/prod workflow so that images stored in 'public' directory has the correct path when deployed to gh-pages. Below is my Tailwind config starting point where 'backgroundImages' property is referencing an image file stored in 'public'.

```html
module.exports = {
  mode:'jit',
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,jsx}"],
  theme: {
    screens: {
      sm: '480px',
      md: '768px',
      lg: '976px',
      xl: '1440px',
    },
    colors: {
      'splash-hex': '#6BD1D2',
      'splash-rgba': 'rgba(107, 209, 210,1.0)',
      'splash-hsla': 'hsla(181, 53%, 62%, 1.0)',
    },
    fontFamily: {
      sans: ['Graphik', 'sans-serif'],
      serif: ['Merriweather', 'serif'],
    },
    backgroundImages:{
      'default':'url("./10475996-3x2-940x627.jpeg")'
    },
    extend: {
      spacing: {
        '128': '32rem',
        '144': '36rem',
      },
      borderRadius: {
        '4xl': '2rem',
      }
    }
  },
  prefix: 'tw-',
  plugins: [],
}
```

In dev this works fine.

`http://localhost:3000/10475996-3x2-940x627.jpeg`

In 'dist' folder, it looks correct as well when 'build' is run.

[image]

When deployed to gh-pages, the path changes to `/assets/` and the image is no longer served from root as I expected according to [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory).

`https://unevenartwork.com/assets/10475996-3x2-940x627.jpeg`

Is there a configuration that would suppress the `/assets/` on deploy or another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this issue has two parts.

First, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71180561/vite-change-ouput-directory-of-assets), on `build` or `deploy` command, Rollup will create the output directories when set in the config. Just place the image assets in `src/img` folder as a target for Rollup to output to dist folder.

Then, in Tailwind config, be sure to make a reference to the parent directory in the asset path - `../img/10475996-3x2-940x627.jpeg` instead of `./img/10475996-3x2-940x627.jpeg`. This helps Vite make the correct path association to the parent directory.

It appears this is effective for properties defined in Tailwind theme extensions. No issues experienced with `img` `src` attribute values.